# When left joining pandas dataframe why the result has less columns than the left dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am working on a project and at one point I need to left join two dataframes: df and temp.
df has around 20 columns and 47576 rows while temp has 4 columns and 446829 rows; the two dataframe have to be joined on three columns (shared by the both of them).
To avoid creating extra Lines I first run the following:

```
    temp = temp.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B','C'])
```

Then I join the two dataframes running the function:

```
    df_1 = pd.merge(df, temp, how='left', left_on=['A','B','C']; right_on=['A','B','C'])
```

I would then assume that the df_1 dataframe has exactly as many rows as df (since it can't have more as I have already dropped the duplicates in temp; and it shouldn't have less as it is a left join).

But I see that actually the df_1 dataframe has 30259 rows which is much less than the 47576 rows the df dataframe had.

How is this possible?

(Also, thinking it could somehow help I filled in the Nan values of the columns 'A','B','C' in the df dataframe but it doesn't seem to help)

Comment: If you can provide a minimal data example it would be easier to answer your question. But either way, try removing the "left_on=" and "right_on=" and replace with "on="

Comment: you can try also using the following syntax to see if you get a different result: 

`df_1 = df.merge(temp, how='left', on=['A', 'B', 'C'])`